# Работа с вводимыми символами

Tags: java, android

У меня есть поле для ввода (обычный `EditText`) и есть счетчик количества введенных символов в данное поле ввода.

Необходимо чтобы при вводе латиницы прибавлялось к счетчику +2 (а не +1, как при вводе других символов).

Стоит ли мне писать проверку на каждый введенный символ пользователя вручную или возможно есть уже готовые решения подобных задач?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Стоит ли мне писать проверку на каждый введенный символ пользователя вручную или возможно есть уже готовые решения подобных задач?

Готовые решения скорее всего и есть, но вот найти их будет проблемой. Да и зачем что-то искать, если решение Вашей задачи – это три строчки кода?!

Так что да, стоит написать метод с подобным функционалом самостоятельно.

Для решения Вашей задачи можно воспользоваться кодами символов:

- Коды символов латиницы в верхнем регистре принадлежат множеству `[65;90]`;
- Коды символов латиницы в нижнем регистре принадлежат множеству `[97;122]`.

Метод, увеличивающий счетчик в соответствии с Вашей логикой, можно реализовать следующим образом:

```
private int incCounter(char c, int counter) {
    int charCode = (int) c;
    if ((c >= 65) && (c <= 90) || (c >= 97) && (c <= 122)) {
        return ++counter;
    } else {
        return counter+2;
    }
}
```

А вообще, с помощью тернарного оператора, код вышеприведенного метода можно записать в одну строчку, но тогда логика работы метода станет чуть менее очевидной и код будет менее читабельным.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать множество с латинским алфавитом. И проверять символ на вхождение в это множество. Это самый простой вариант.